# How do call the template for a module block

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

My goal is create a custom block that uses a twig template that you can pass info to via the theme function like so.

```
  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->siteContent(),
    );
  }

  public function siteContent() {

    $source_text = some_function_returning_html_from_user();

    return array(
      '#theme' => 'scadfashblock',
      '#source_text' => $source_text,
    );
  }
```

I got the above code from a tutorial trying to render a template file for a custom page. The problem is this code throws an error saying that an *array can't be returned this way, it must be a string*.

I even tried doing it the drupal 7 way...

```
  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->siteContent(),
    );
  }

  private function siteContent() {

    $output = array();
    $output['source_text'] = some_function_returning_html_from_user();

    return theme('scadfashblock', $output);
  }
```

This throws an error:

> Call to undefined function `Drupal\<module>\Plugin\Block\theme()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `markup` render `#type` takes a string for its `#markup` element property, not a render array. However you do not need to wrap your custom theme/template with the markup type.

```
  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'scadfashblock',
      '#source_text' => $this->siteContent(),
    );
  }

  public function siteContent() {
    return some_function_returning_html_from_user();
  }
```

Then implement `scadfashblock` in hook_theme, provide a `template_preprocess_scadfashblock` and a `templates/scadfashblock.html.twig` with your markup.

Answer (score 2):

First you implement Hook_theme like in D7

```
function preosasde_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
      'similar_readings' => array(
          'variables' => array('readings' => NULL),
      )
  );
}
```

Then you create a render array that specifies the theme and the necessary variables as build() of your block:

```
foreach ($similar as $id => $data) {
      $sims[] = array('title' => $data['title'],
          'modified' => $data['date'], 'url' => $library->getAsdeUrl($id));
    }
return ['#theme' => 'similar_readings', '#readings' => $sims];
```

And finally you define a template in your module (or theme)

/templates/similar-readings.html.twig:

```
<table class='table table-striped table-condensed'>
                <tr><th>Datum</th><th>Titel</th></tr>
            {% if readings|length > 0 %}        
              {% for artikel in readings %} 
                <tr>
                        <td>{{ artikel.modified|date("d.m.Y") }}</td>
                        <td><a href="/{{ artikel.url }}">{{ artikel.title }}</a></td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <tr><td colspan="2"><em>keine</em></td></tr>
            {% endif %}
 </table>
```

You don't need the hook_preprocess anymore. But don't forget to clear the cache!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting *Call to undefined function `Drupal\<module>\Plugin\Block\theme()`* simply because you are using `theme()` without qualifying it with its namespace; since that code is in a file using a namespace, PHP things you are using a function in the same namespace. If Drupal still had `theme()` as function, in that file you should call it as `\theme()`, but since that function doesn't exist in Drupal 8, you need to change the code you are using.

Calling a theme function is not different from what you would do in Drupal 7 when using a render array.

```
  public function build() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'scadfashblock',
      '#source_text' => $this->siteContent(),
    );
  }

  private function siteContent() {
    // Add your code to populate source_text.
  }
```

See also [theme() renamed to _theme() and should not be called directly](https://www.drupal.org/node/2195739), where it is explained that Drupal 8 modules should not use `theme()`.